# Not able to convert dataframe index from datetime format

Tags: python, pandas

[download link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7cb84543cbe79207fec9043931d3c77420190513122513/218ce3)[1](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7cb84543cbe79207fec9043931d3c77420190513122513/218ce3)I have extracted raw data from the a csv file and I have set the index column to Date.Here is in the attached clip
[image]

The index is not in datetime format and when I try to convert using the below code

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

I get this error:

```
 "ValueError: month must be in 1..12"
```

The current `dtype` for the index is `'object'`

I have seen some previous questions related to conversion to datetime but am afraid I couldn't use that to get a solution to my question. Could someone help please?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem 3 different types of datetimes - solution is parse each separately - for unmatched values are created `NaN`s, so for replace them use [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('FFdata1.csv', index_col=['Date'])

df = df.reset_index()

#format YYDDMM
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%y%d%m', errors='coerce')
#format YYYY
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y', errors='coerce')
#format YYYYMM
d3 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce')

df['Date'] = d1.combine_first(d2).combine_first(d3)

#check not parsed datetimes
print(df[df['Date'].isna()])
     Date  Mkt-RF  SMB  HML   RF
1113  NaT     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1114  NaT     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1115  NaT  Mkt-RF  SMB  HML   RF
1208  NaT     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1209  NaT     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Another possible solution is create 3 separate DataFrames:

```
df = pd.read_csv('FFdata1.csv', index_col=['Date'])

df = df.reset_index()

#format YYDDMM
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%y%d%m', errors='coerce')
df1 = df.assign(Date=d1).dropna(subset=['Date'])
print (df1.head())
        Date Mkt-RF    SMB    HML    RF
0 2019-07-26   2.96   -2.3  -2.87  0.22
1 2019-08-26   2.64   -1.4   4.19  0.25
2 2019-09-26   0.36  -1.32   0.01  0.23
3 2019-10-26  -3.24   0.04   0.51  0.32
4 2019-11-26   2.53   -0.2  -0.35  0.31
```

---

```
#format YYYY
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y', errors='coerce')
df2 = df.assign(Date=d2).dropna(subset=['Date'])
print (df2.head())
           Date  Mkt-RF    SMB     HML    RF
1116 1927-01-01   29.47  -2.46   -3.75  3.12
1117 1928-01-01   35.39    4.2   -6.15  3.56
1118 1929-01-01  -19.54  -30.8   11.81  4.75
1119 1930-01-01  -31.23  -5.13  -12.28  2.41
1120 1931-01-01  -45.11   3.53  -14.29  1.07
```

---

```
#format YYYYMM
d3 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce')
df3 = df.assign(Date=d3).dropna(subset=['Date'])
print (df3.head())
        Date Mkt-RF    SMB    HML    RF
0 1926-07-01   2.96   -2.3  -2.87  0.22
1 1926-08-01   2.64   -1.4   4.19  0.25
2 1926-09-01   0.36  -1.32   0.01  0.23
3 1926-10-01  -3.24   0.04   0.51  0.32
4 1926-11-01   2.53   -0.2  -0.35  0.31
```

Comment: thanks jezrael, I got another error "ValueError: day is out of range for month"

Comment: thanks again,  giving 835 out of 1112 entries. there must be some way to fix these dates.

Comment: not 'completely' fixed unfortunately, it converts to datetime but the numbers are all wrong. the first entry is year 1926 and month 7 if you look at the pic above. The converted datetime I see is 2019-07-26.

Comment: @PrasKam - Are data confidental? Is possible share `pd.Series(df.index).to_csv(file, index=False)` ?

Comment: sure could send you the file. Can you help me do that as am not able to find out how to upload a file. thanks again

Comment: @PrasKam - You ca try gdocs, dropbox, wetransfer or similar services.

Comment: and then share url link.

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7cb84543cbe79207fec9043931d3c77420190513122513/218ce3 here you go

Comment: am actually taking only first 1111 entries

Comment: legend! thanks so much for all the help. that really was very helpful !

Answer (score 0):

The file contains more than one data series. The beginning of the file has a header line and then dates formatted as `%Y%m`. But at line 1115, we find a line containing only empty values, followed with a textual information (Annual Factors: January-December), a new header line and than annual data with date formatted as `%Y` only. This is far beyond what `read_csv` can automagically process.

So my advice is to first load the file without trying to parse the `Date` column, then reject any line past the first one containing an empty date, and only then parse the date on the remaining lines.

Code could be:

```
df = pd.read_csv('FFdata1.csv').loc[df.index < df[df.Date.isna()].index[0]]
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%Y%m')
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```